# Multiple Countdowntimers in a Listview

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an application with multiple countdowntimers ticking on the Main Activity. The timers will have an object string as will showing in the the list view. Problem is that the timer(s) are not ticking down, it stays static.

Here's the section of my Main Activity

```
 final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        final ArrayAdapter ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,BountyList);
        list.setAdapter(ListAdapter);
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BountyList.get(0).getTime().start();
                ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

r.run();
```

Here is the object class that handles my string and keeps my timer object.

```
public class Bounty {
String BountyName;
String URL;
String timelapse;
int BountyAmount;
long exHour, exMin, exSec;
CountDownTimer time;
//ArrayAdapter a;

public Bounty(String name, String url,int Amount,long hour, long min, long sec){//maybe add Adapter as local to handle it here?
    BountyName = name;
    BountyAmount = Amount;
    exHour = hour *60*60*1000;
    exMin = min *60* 1000;
    exSec = sec *1000;
    URL = url;
    final long test = (exHour+exMin+exSec) ;
    //a = adapter;
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    time = new CountDownTimer(test,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //long test2 = -1;
            //if(test2 == -1){
            //    test2 = test;
            //}
            //test2 = test2 - 1000;
            timelapse = toHourFormat(millisUntilFinished);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();// not ticking so wont show toString
}
public String toString(){
    if(timelapse==null){
        timelapse = "Issue Here";
    }
    return BountyName+" | "+ BountyAmount+" | " + timelapse;
}
public String toHourFormat(long milli){
    int second = (int) (milli / 1000) % 60 ;
    int minutes = (int) ((milli / (1000*60)) % 60);
    int hours = (int) ((milli / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
    return hours+":"+minutes+":"+second;
}
public CountDownTimer getTime(){
    return time;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The countdowntimer has to be executed in an activity class so that it can run. This can be done by extending the a class like so,

```
public class timeractivity extends Activity{
        //run timer here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the following runnable (in your given code) is not executed?

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        BountyList.get(0).getTime().start();
        ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Comment: @Ossusum do you call `.run()` on this `Runnable`?

Comment: Yes I did, still won't tick down